# JsPDF & Html2canvas - Image cut off if "multiple" page

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I have a page that lists multiple products. A single product is split into 3 separate divs. I am looping through each product and converting each div into a separate html2canvas image, resulting in a single product having 3 pages in a PDF (one for each div)

This works fine with 1 product (3 pages in pdf), however anymore (e.g. 4th page on PDF) and the top of the image starts to get cut off for some reason.

Here is the code i am using

```
var doc = new jsPDF(1, "pt", "letter");
(async function loop(){
<?php 
    $count = 0; 
    foreach($products as $k => $v){ 
    $count++; 
    ?>
var k = '<?php echo $k; ?>';
for(var i=1;i<4;i++){
    await new Promise(function(resolve){
        html2canvas($("#pdfcontent"+i+"_"+k)[0], {scale: 2}).then((canvas) => {
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 0,  590.28, 590.28/canvas.width * canvas.height);
            if (i < 3){
                doc.addPage();
            }else{
                <?php if ($count == count($products)){ ?>
                doc.save('test.pdf');
                <?php }else{ ?>
                doc.addPage();
                <?php } ?>
            }
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
<?php 
    } 
    ?>
})();
```

Here is screenshots of the issue, you can see on the second image the header is gone even know it's using the exact same code above that created the first image.

First Image
[image: Screenshot DOWC 1]

Second Image
[image: Screenshot DOWC 2]

Any help with a solution to this would be greatly appreciated, thank you.